# Why is my custom hotkey for adding a mirror modifier not working?

Tags: modifiers, shortcut, mirror-modifier

I've set up a custom shortcut for adding a mirror modifier in Object Mode. When I try using it, it won't execute. I use ⌘1 for setting a sub surface, and that is applied just fine. Do I have something set up wrong here? I've seen that having Emulate Numpad enabled can mess things up, but I also have that disabled.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hide Collection has a higher priority, disable it.

Comment: That was it! Thanks